# Angular JS - UI-Router: Reload state on click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I'am using Angular JS with UI-Router,

I want to reload state, when we click on the state link from the same state.

I fixed it with the following code,

```
<a ui-sref="page1" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">Page 1</a>
```

But it is tedious to add `ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}"` in all the links.

So I want a configuration or settings or code in angular js( or ui-router) to manage this globally. That is if we click on state link from the same state, the state should get reloaded.

Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: You can write your own directive that will do that

Comment: do you want to reinitialize the controller with the newly resolved values ?

Comment: @dennyjohn : yes, I want to reinitialize controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to go here is to adjust `$state.go` implementation, e.g. like this:

#### [Changing the default behavior of $state.go() in ui.router to reload by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23144566/1679310)

In general we will use **`decorator`** to get control over $state behaviour

```
.config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$state', function ($delegate) {

        // let's locally use 'state' name
        var state = $delegate;
        ...
```

see that [in action here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23174507/1679310)

Why that should work is described here:

#### [Difference between ui-sref and $state.go in AngularJS UI-Router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24526801/1679310)